# Choose function according to ternary operators

Tags: javascript

I've a code:

```
a=function(x){alert(x)}
b=function(x){document.write(x)}
c=1;
[c==1?a:b](':p');
```

but it's not working. Is possible to do what I want?

Comment: Why do people like to write such unreadable code?  For goodness sakes, use an `if/else` and make your code reaadable.  If you want small size, then minimized it afterwards.  My priorities are "correct", "readable/maintainable", "compact", "fast".  Only on a very few occasions (usually after detailed performance profiling) is it worth sacrificing either of the first two for speed or size.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, just replace the square brackets with parentheses. You are creating an array literal, but you want to isolate an expression:

```
(c==1?a:b)(':p');
```

This would also work, but there is no reason to use it:

```
[c==1?a:b][0](':p');
```

Comment: Hmm.. and what about jQuery? I can't.. help please

$(element)(c==1?attr:css)(agrument);

Comment: In this case you need brackets :-) `$(element)[c==1?'attr':'css']('?')`